# How to transform a set of commands into a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I would like to transform this set of commands into a loop.

```
 sbj05_GD = load("ep_sbj05_GD.Rdata")
 sbj06_GD = load("ep_sbj06_GD.Rdata")
 sbj08_GD = load("ep_sbj08_GD.Rdata")
 sbj09_GD = load("ep_sbj09_GD.Rdata")

 sbj05_max <-max(sbj05_GD$A)
 sbj06_max <-max(sbj06_GD$A)
 sbj08_max <-max(sbj08_GD$A)
 sbj09_max <-max(sbj09_GD$A)

 max_sum <- rbind(sbj05_max,sbj06_max,sbj08_max,sbj09_max)
 max_sum <-as.data.frame(max_sum)
 colnames(max_sum) <- c("max")
 max_sum$sbj <- c("sbj05","sbj06","sbj08","sbj09")

 write.table(max_sum, file = "Ep_max_sum.txt",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
```

I started with this attempt, which doesn't work, but I am not even sure how I could rbind the files in a loop.

```
file=list.files("path/", pattern="*.Rdata", full.names="TRUE")
for (i in 1:file){
data=load(file[i])
data_max[i] <-max(file[i]$A)
}
```

I am not very familiar with loops, so I would be grateful if you could suggest how to proceed, and if a for loop is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
file.codes <- c("05", "06", "08", "09")
max_sum <- data.frame(sbj = file.codes, max = NA)
for (i in file.codes) {
    load(paste0("ep_sbj", i, "_GD.Rdata"))
    max_sum[max_sum$sbj == i, "max"] <- max(obj$A)
}
```

Line 1 creates a vector of the file codes (which it seems are subject numbers). Line 2 creates the data frame where you will store everything. The `for` loop loops through the file codes and extracts the file based on the the file code, and then assigns to the correct position in the data frame the value you want from the data set. This assumes that using `load()` creates a data frame or list called "`obj`"; otherwise replace `obj` with its actual name. Presumably this is the same for each file. There are likely more eloquent ways to do this, but this one is straightforward.

In two lines, you could do:

```
file.codes <- c("05", "06", "08", "09")
max_sum <- data.frame(sbj = file.codes, 
                      max = sapply(file.codes, function(i) {
                          load(paste0("ep_sbj", i, "_GD.Rdata"))
                          return(max(obj$A))
                             }))
```

which uses `sapply()` instead of `for` to loop.

Edited in accordance with @42's comment.

Comment: This will probably not work.  The R `load` command does not necessarily return a value that is suitable to be assigned to a name. The result returned for `load` is only the _names_ of the items that were loaded .... NOT their values. If you want to save a file and have the value assigned to a name then it must be saved with `saveRDS`.

Comment: You're right. `load()` will suffice without the assignment to `temp`. Edited.

Comment: Glad you recognized that. But your claim that your code could working in anycircumstance is likewise false.